# VS MVC Project CSS Minification fails when using CSS variables

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, minify

In Visual Studio, Minification is failing for me in my MVC project when I introduce any variables in my bundled css files.  Example:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(3,5): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '-'
(6,23): run-time error CSS1039: Token not allowed after unary operator: '-main-bg-color'
 */
:root {
    /*DEFAULT COLORS LINES*/
    --main-bg-color: rgb(34,34,34);
}
body{
background-color:var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

other minifiers work just fine, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: ? Report a bug. (It also fails with `@import` and newlines in strings (`'\a'` becomes `'\n'` which is not valid CSS).

Comment: really strange this isn't more of a hot-button issue, please update us if you have a fix

Comment: I ended up using SCSS + Web Compiler in VS, as it has its own internal variable handlers and also will do minification.

Comment: And then it was 2022 and this was still a problem... :|

Comment: In March 2024 I had this error in an updated visual studio. It just suddenly appeared when I had not changed my CSS.

After a frantic 30 minutes I restarted Visual Studio and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) as a twofold solution which allows both a multitude of variable methods along with minification.

Answer (score 3):

The BundlerMinifier library used in visual studio for magnifying CSS is currently unable to handle CSS variables.

This issue has been raised on github https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/218 /  https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify/issues/17.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This still needs to be fixed by Microsoft. Frustrating.

Comment: @Jeremy I agree. Variables have been part of the CSS standard for a while now.